# PHP join is adding a comma before the first value

Tags: php, jquery, sql

I am using a join statement in `PHP` and it's adding a comma before the first value. I'm not sure why.

Here is the code

```
$columns = join(', ', $column_names). ' ';
```

Here is the result

```
,value1, value2, value3
```

It's sent using `AJAX`, and here's how the array is created on the front end using `jQuery`.

```
$('#preview_button').click(function() {
    var rc_column_names = ['not', 'set'];
    if($('#rc_custom_columns').is(':checked')) {
        rc_column_names = [];
        $(".list2 li").each(function() {
            rc_column_names.push($(this).text());
         });
    }

    $.ajax({
        url:'core/functions/create_report_preview.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: { 'rc_column_names': rc_column_names }
    }).fail (function(data) {
        //code
    }).done(function(data) {
        //code
    });
});
```

So again, the question is. Where is this comma coming from? Why is it added before the first value?

Comment: `join()` is not.  The comma is already there in the first element.

Comment: `var_dump($column_names)`. `join()` will only insert the new separator **BETWEEN** elements that already exist. If you get a comma at the start of your joined string, then you have an EMPTY element in your array to begin with. e.g. your JS code is screwing up and creating an empty element. PHP is doing exactly what it was told to.

Comment: Or what @MarcB said :-)

Comment: @MarcB that was my thought exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have an empty value as your first array element. Use `array_filter()` before calling `join()` to remove empty values from your array.

Comment: What a nifty tool, I was unaware of it's existence. Ignorance is yet again my downfall, =). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If it's actually `, value1, value2, value3` (with a space after the first comma), then $column_names` must have a blank string as the first value.

Otherwise, the comma is coming from other code. It could be part of your first value, it could be a typo in other code. Try doing a `var_dump($column_names)`.

Comment: Thanks Jessica, and I agree with you. I just can't seem to find anywhere that a null, or empty string is being added. I guess I just wanted to confirm my suspicion. I'll start dumping and echoing things to see what comes out.

Comment: In the future, you do the echo and var_dump tests *before* SO. ;)